# Qt writing appdata .ini file

Tags: c++, qt, ini

in my Qt5 application I use functions to read and write to .ini file localised in appdata/roaming/AppName/config. I'm reading any lines from fille successfully, but I can't write to it. Could you help me with this?

```
appData = QFileInfo(myapp.fileName()).absolutePath();
QSettings setting(appData + "/config/settings.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
        setting.sync();
        setting.beginGroup("/Settings");
        setting.setValue("/Language", 1); //"Language" variable after this line is the same as befre
        setting.endGroup();
```

If .ini file is localsed in another location (eg. "D" drive), writing works.

Comment: No, in appdata are only configuration files

Comment: Then you need to pass the path of AppData. Not the path of your program.

Comment: You should use QStandardPaths to get that: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#StandardLocation-enum

Comment: Patch to Appdata is good... appdata variable is giving patch: "C:/Users/(UserName)/AppData/Roaming/(AppName)", and I said that reading form this localisation is working...

Comment: Try calling `settings.sync()` after setting values. AFAIK `QSettings` is buffered object and doesn't write to file just after `setValue`. If you want to avoid calling `sync` then make sure that the destructor is called before checking your file.

Comment: Oh. I am sorry. You have variables named `appdata` and `appData` which confused me.. `appdata` is not correct but you are not using that..

Comment: @drescherjm yes, sorry I wrote "appdata", but it in my code it is "appData"... I have edited my post :)

Comment: @Rames when I called sync() after setting value, it changed in .ini file, so you have solved my issue - thanks :)